# Which distribution has the following variance formula?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given a set of data $x_i$, for $i=1\ldots N$. I know their variance is calculated by

$$\sigma^2 = A \sum_{i=2}^N \ln^2\left(\frac{x_i}{x_{i-1}}\right)$$

where $A$ is a constant.

how can I determine how my data set is distributed?

Comment: What is $A$? Some arbitrary fitting constant? Or a parameter related to the underlying population parameter?

Comment: Do yo mean that $\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N(x-\overline x)^2= A \sum_{i=2}^N \ln^2\left(\frac{x_i}{x_{i-1}}\right)$ ??

Comment: yes, sorry, $A$ is some fixed parameter. I edited the question

Comment: There is something weird going on here. Since the $x_1$, $x_2$ etc all have a different role in computing the variance it must be case that they are not drawn independently from the same distribution. It somehow looks like as if observing the value of $x_i$ changes the distribution of $x_{i+1}$. Is this true? Do you have more information about how the data is generated that led you to this formula? Are you willing to share that extra information with us?

Comment: Yes, $x_i$ represent daily observations of a financial stock index (in my case the EuroStoxx50, but this might be applied to other indices)